# Finding the "operatorial" norm of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ with $T(x_n)_n=(\dfrac{x_2}{2}, \dfrac{x_3}{3},...,\dfrac{x_n}{n},...)$ and $\ell^2 = \{(x_n)_n \in \mathbb{C} | \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 < \infty \}$

I already proved that $T$ is linear and bounded, i.e. $||T(x_n)_n|| \leq \dfrac{1}{2} ||(x_n)_n||$.

This result gives me only an overestimation of the norm of $T$ in the space of all linear amd bounded operators ($\mathcal{L}(\ell^2)$).

Now, I know that the actual value of the operatorial norm I'm looking for is exactly $\frac12$, but to prove this I need an underestimation of it.

I tried to use the sup definition of the operatorial norm for sequences of norm $1$, but couldn't find the desired inequality.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take $(x_{n})_{n} = (0, 1, 0, 0, \dots)=e_{2}$, then $||T(e_{2})|| = \frac{1}{2} ||e_{2}||$.

Comment: Right. Thank you!